# How to properly use NativeScript WebView without rendering it?

Tags: android, ios, webview, nativescript

I want to use NativeScript's WebView to preprocess some of my data (it uses XHTML so I must use WebView and it's evaluateJavascript method).

But for the preprocess I don't want to render the whole WebView just for a blink of an eye time, so I created a service which creates a `new WebView()` instance. Now I can set the src attribute this way and all others, like height and with, but if I want to call the evaluateJavascript function I can't. Code below.

```
test() {
//create new webview instance
    this.wv = new WebView();

//all of this works
    this.wv.set('height', 100);
    this.wv.setProperty('width', 200);
    this.wv.setProperty('src', 'some url here'); 

//this does not work
this.wv.android.evaluateJavascript(
      'function test(){ return 1;} test();',
      new android.webkit.ValueCallback({
        onReceiveValue: function (res: any) {
          console.log(res);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

The set and setProperty methods are fine, but the `evaluateJavascript` says it can't be called on undefined.

```
console.log(this.wv.android); //undefined
```

Also the WebView loaded event does not run, if have something like this in the test function above.

```
this.wv.on('loadFinished', (data) => {
      console.log('loadFinished');
      console.dir(data);
    });
```

On the other hand, if I create a component, put a WebView element in it, than listen for the loadFinished event, than i can run the JS seen above, like this:

```
webViewLoaded(webargs) {
    // console.log('WEBVIEW LOADED');
   this.webView = webargs.object;
   this.webVie.android.evaluateJavascript(
      'function test(){ return 1;} test();',
      new android.webkit.ValueCallback({
        onReceiveValue: function (res: any) {
          console.log(res);
        }
      })
    );
  }
//It run properly.
  }
```

So my questions are:

Am I right and the loadFinished event does not run on the creation of new WebView() instance? If it does run, how can I add a listener to it?

What's the difference between the instance of new WebView() and the object returned in the args param above? And why this.wv.android is undefined in the test function above?

Can I run evaluateJavascript on a WebView instance that does not have any HTML counterpart and is not even rendered out? If yes, how?

Am I obligated to render the WebView to use it properly?

Comment: Good question my friend!